# how to create friendly url in my directory using php

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I use these type of URL:

```
http://test.com/rest/api.php?action=test
```

But I need these type URL:

```
http://test.com/rest/api/action/test
```

I try to `.htaccess` file these code here

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code by relacing your code your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/rest` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rest/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/?$ api.php?action=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^rest/api.php?action=test$ /rest/api/action/test [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule` doesn't match query string.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal can be achieved by using regular expressions with syntax like :

```
RewriteRule ^rest/api/action/(\d+)*$ ./rest/api.php?action=$1
```

try read these articles :

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/ and
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/